# Jersey rest api not working on compute engine tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, jersey, google-compute-engine

jersey rest api service is working fine on localhost tomcat7 but when i trying to deploy on tomcat8 on google compute engine it is not working i even tried with tomcat7 also but still 404 resource not found (it working fine on localhost tomcat7) plz help me:(

here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RestTest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Hello.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  </web-app>
```

And Here is my Rest Service Test Class

\
package com.services;

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.obj.Resp;

@Path("/say")
public class Test {

    @Path("/hello")
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) 
    public static Resp name() {
      Resp res=new Resp();
      res.setName("name");
      res.setPass("pass");
      System.out.println("Testing");
        return res;

    }

    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    public static String defaul() {
        return "Hello Rest Api";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be problem with context-path.
local entry point looks something like http://localhost:8888/rest/yourEntry

via your configuration

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Try to change it to:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Hope it will resolve your problem

Comment: thank you for the help , I tried it but  still same problem 404 i dont what happening